# NodeJS - How can I use a function to set a listeners callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

```
var events = require('events');
var requests = new events.EventEmitter();
function setListenerCallback(callback) {
    requests.on('randomEvent', callback(message));
}
setListenerCallback(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
Result: callback is undefined.
```

As you can see I am trying to set the listeners callback function from a functions argument. The result is that the function is type 'undefined' and therefore **outside of the listeners scope**.

*So how can I use a function to set a listeners callback?

How can I access the parent functions scope from the listener?*

Comment: Are you sure you're passing a function to `setListenerCallback()`? Also if `callback(message)` doesn't return a function you'll have to wrap it in an anonymous function.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now!
I was passing callback(message) as argument instead of just callback. I guess I need some sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the code:

Old code:

```
var events = require('events');
var requests = new events.EventEmitter();
function setListenerCallback(callback) {
    requests.on('randomEvent', callback(message));
}
setListenerCallback(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

New code:

```
var events = require('events');
var requests = new events.EventEmitter();
function setListenerCallback(callback) {
    requests.on('randomEvent', callback);
}
setListenerCallback(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Now when the event is fired callback is called.